# React Hooks - Dynamically Render Text Inputs and Store Inputs as One Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-hooks

I have a user model that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Sun12",
    "role": "1",
    "email": "sun12@gmail.com",
    "password": "test123",
    "about": "This is a description of me.",
    "skills": ["Acting", "Music", "Art", "English Literature"],
    "studying": "Mind Control"
}
```

I want to create a form that will capture the above users information.

The `skills` field in the user schema is arbitrarily long - I want users to be able to add as many skills as they like.

How can I dynamically render text input fields, and send each of the inputs to those dynamically rendered fields to the `skills` array?

Here is my entire `Signup.js` file:

```
// users Signin

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Layout from '../core/Layout';
import {API} from '../config';

const Signup = () => {

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    studying: '',
    skills: [],
    error: '',
    success: ''
  });

  const {name, email, password, studying} = values;


  const signup = (user) => {
    fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

  const clickSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    signup({name, email, password, studying});
  };

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({...values, error: false, [name]: event.target.value});
  };



  const signUpForm = () => (
    <form>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="text-muted">Name</label>
            <input onChange={handleChange('name')} type="text" className ="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="text-muted">Email</label>
            <input onChange={handleChange('email')} type="email" className ="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="text-muted">Password</label>
            <input onChange={handleChange('password')} type="password" className="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="text-muted">Studying</label>
            <input onChange={handleChange('studying')} type="text" className ="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>{createInputs()}</div>
            <button onClick={addSkill}>Add</button>
        </div>

        <button onClick={clickSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">
          Sign Up
        </button>

    </form>
  );


  return(
  <Layout 
    title="Signup" 
    description="Join today."
    className="container col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      {signUpForm()}
      {JSON.stringify(values)}
  </Layout>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the array with `.map()` to render an input corresponding to each skill. Then set-up some event-handlers that let you update that skill and create new skills by adding another item into the array.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-bhaskara-gdxwm

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const User = ({ data }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    role: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    about: "",
    skills: [],
    studying: ""
  });

  const createInputs = () => {
    return user.skills.map((skill, idx) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <input value={skill} onChange={e => updateSkill(e, idx)} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  const updateSkill = (e, index) => {
    const userCopy = { ...user };
    userCopy.skills[index] = e.target.value;
    setUser(userCopy);
  };

  const removeSkill = index => {
    const userCopy = { ...user };
    const userCopySkills = [...userCopy.skills];

    userCopySkills.splice(index, 1);

    setUser({
      ...userCopy,
      skills: [...userCopySkills]
    });
  };

  const addSkill = () => {
    setUser(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState.user,
        skills: [...prevState.skills, ""]
      };
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user);
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{createInputs()}</div>
      <button onClick={addSkill}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default User;
```

I threw in the `useEffect()` there just to show you that the skills array is getting updated. You can take it off if you'd like.